# How to use simple html form to get value from rest service?

Tags: java, html, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have simle controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/raport")
public class SiteController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{url}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMovie(@PathVariable String url, ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("url", url);
        return "raport";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDefaultMovie(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("url", "this is default movie url");
        return "raport";

    }

}
```

if I call `http://localhost:8090/movieraport/raport/testMovie` i got a correct response from server

Movie url : testMovie

but I want to have a little form on page like this (.jsp):

```
<body>
<form action="raport/" method="get">
    <input name="url" />
    <input type="submit" value="Update Record">
</form>

<h3>Movie url : ${url}</h3>
```

When I clicked to submit I got url like this

```
http://localhost:8090/movieraport/raport/raport?url=testMovie
```

and server is not working with {testMovie} :(

I got:

Movie url : raport

Can you help me?

Comment: This is not a problem. movieraport/raport/testMovie works. movieraport/raport/?url=testMovie not works

Comment: You should also review how a browser behaves with particular values that a `form`'s `action` attribute can take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass "url" as a parameter, you need to do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMovie(@RequestParam String url, ...) {
    ...
}
```

You are incorrectly assuming that "url=" should be passed to your "/{url}" mapping, I imagine. Simply use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable` OR create yet another method to allow support for both if that's what you need.

**EDIT**

After your comments, I should emphasize that I have no way of knowing what your use case is or all of the endpoints you may need, but from the exception you gave, it sounds like you did nothing more than replace your `getMovie()` with my `getMovie()` and now the signature conflicts with your `getDefaultMovie()`. You can easily vary the signatures as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", params = "url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMovie(@RequestParam String url, ...) {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getDefaultMovie(...) {
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I have added `params = "url"` to the `getMovie()` signature. This will make sure `getMovie()` is used to process any requests that include a `url` parameter. The rest will go to `getDefaultMovie()`.

Comment: I changed but it isn't work, app cannot set up with errors: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'siteController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.my.siteraport.controller.SiteController.getMovie(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
to {[/raport/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'siteController' bean meth
public java.lang.String com.my.siteraport.controller.SiteController.getDefaultMovie(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) mapped.

Comment: btw. How can I do it in the best way?

Comment: Thanks a lot kungfuters!